# Can not Getting the Filter "CICMYKHalftone"

Tags: filter

I am just Trying to fixed the filter "CICMYKHalftone" but  "*cMYKHalftone" is not getting the the filter...

```
 CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage      imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"]];
CIFilter *cMYKHalftone = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CICMYKHalftone"];
[cMYKHalftone setDefaults]; 
[cMYKHalftone setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[cMYKHalftone setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:150 Y:150] forKey:@"inputCenter"];
[cMYKHalftone setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:6.00] forKey:@"inputWidth"];
[cMYKHalftone setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.00] forKey:@"inputAngle"];
[cMYKHalftone setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.70] forKey:@"inputSharpness"];
[cMYKHalftone setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.00] forKey:@"inputGCR"];
[cMYKHalftone setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.50] forKey:@"inputUCR"];
CIImage *outputImage = [cMYKHalftone valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
theImageview.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:outputImage.extent]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This filter is not available for iOS.